# How do I get past the laser detectors in the mission Searching for Proof?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm playing through the Searching for Proof mission in Deus Ex Human Revolution. I've gotten to the part where there are the sweeping laser detectors. I couldn't figure out how to get past, so I found a walkthrough and it shows the below laser gate flickering and going out so that you can slip through.

However, for me it never flickers and remains constantly on. Is this a bug or did I miss something?

[image: laser door]

Comment: It seems to be an (undocumented) change coming from the director's cut version of the game. The only thing I found is this forum post: http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=140121

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Invisibility ability to sneak past the lasers. While invisible, you won't trigger them.

http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Glass-Shield_Cloaking_System

Comment: Good answer. I just want to add that you do not have to get past the laser to reach your mission goal. It's just the easier (but not the only) way.